# Perl XML::DOM issues with ASCII XML?

Tags: xml, perl

I'm relatively new to Perl, writing some XML parsing scripts.  I have done two successfully, and this is my third one. I am running into issues which I think are tied to the XML document being ASCII encoded.

I am using Fedora 14 with httpd/apache/perl

I do have

```
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
```

in my web script, so I do see errors on the web page, for the most part, but for the following error, I am not seeing any error on the screen except the generic Apache "500 internal server error," and the httpd error log simply states "Premature end of script headers"

Here is the gist of the code:

```
my $cparser = new XML::DOM::Parser;
my $refdoc = $cparser->parse($cfile, ProtocolEncoding => 'US-ASCII');
findmynodes $refdoc; 
...
sub findmynodes
{
my @refnode = $_0->findnodes("/conf:ConfModel");
...
```

I'm sure $_[0] OK, because if I print $_0 to a file I see "XML::DOM::Document=ARRAY(0x8bb65b8)"

I'm also sure findnodes is the culprit.  Event if I do findnodes("//*") it fails.

Does anybody know what the issue could be?  How can I find more info on what is failing?

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: in your code do you have `$_[0]` or `$_0` ? `$_0` is not the same thing as `$_[0]`, it's just the scalar variable `$_0`. `use strict;` would tell you that.

Comment: Yes, @mirod, that's the answer :)  Do you want to post an answer so I can mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate answer: `$_0` is not `$_[0]`, it's the scalar variable `$_0`. `use strict;` would tell you that.

Also, if you can, do not use XML::DOM, [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/) is more recent, better maintained, more powerful... you name it. `ProtocolEncoding` is also a dangerous option, it means that you do not trust the encoding declaration in the XML. In such a case I usually check, and if necessary fix, the encoding before parsing the file. This way I have a clean, well formed XML file.

Comment: My hosting account doesn't have LibXML, unfortunately.  I'll have to work on copying that to my home directory and get it working.  As for the encoding, the document is ASCII instead of US-ASCII, so I am crossing my fingers for the moment and will address that next.

Comment: it won't work then, XML::LibXML is based on libxml2, so you would need it to be installed, and to have a compiler. It won't work. BTW, it looks like you're using XML::DOM::XPath, at least you have this going for you ;--)

Comment: ericp, [us-ascii is the same as ascii](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets).